# Determine video framerate and audio samplerate with mediacodec

Tags: android, audio, video, decoder, android-mediacodec

I need to figure the following information about some videos I'm decoding with MediaCodec on android: - for audio: sample rate and number of channels; - for video: frame rate. 
I'm usually decoding h264+aac, but the solution should be extendable to other formats. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done not with `MediaCodec`, but with `MediaFormat` instance:

```
format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);
```

(see other keys in documentation)

Comment: Thank you, it works for audio, but for video it does not work (format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE)). Do you have some hints for video too?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't work with video with Media API. But `KEY_FRAME_RATE` seems to be video property. May be there is an issue with input video format.

Comment: There is no input issue, KEY_FRAME_RATE is only supported for encoders, but not for decoders. You have to compute the frame rate manually if you want to get it.